# how to read using InputStreamReader without blocking

Tags: java, inputstream

Is there a simple way to turn the standard code:

```
in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
String message = "";
while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1){
    message += new String(buf, 0, size);
}
```

so that `read()` won't block. I tried doing:

```
if (!in.ready())
   //throw exception
```

but this throws an exception all the time. Maybe:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(120000);
in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
```

but this, as stated by everyone below, doesn't work. Other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which kind of InputStream is backing your reader and if you are using a fixed-length character encoding for the reader, you may be able to use the available method on the backing stream. For most implementations of InputStream, `available()` will return the number of bytes you can read without blocking. If the character encoding uses a fixed number of bytes per character, you know how much you can read from the InputStreamReader without blocking.

Answer (score 2):

*To "prevent blocking" either*...

1) Use NIO (which requires the use of Channels underneath); or a nicer wrapper about NIO use as MINA, [XNIO](http://www.jboss.org/xnio), xSocket, etc. I do not recommend using NIO directly as there are a number of issues to deal with.

2) Use threads; make sure to employ standard thread-data isolation rules to avoid headaches. [Concurrency-aware data-structures](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/jdk/150/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) such as ConcurrentLinkedQueue are your friends.

setSoTimeout does not prevent blocking; it merely adds a timeout to blocking operations. I avoid it because of the numerous "quirks" it has. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Or the new asynchronous API (part of "More NIO Features") in JDK7.

Comment: 1- it sounds like that's an external package. If so, I'll try to solve the problem without external packages

2- I'm already using threading